# How to update an item on the list inside the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

Given this data structure for each "totalLiabilities" I need to do a calculation of ("totalAssets" - "shareholderEquity"). How it would be in javascript. Much appreciated.

```
{
    "symbol": "FB",
    "financials": [
        {
            "reportDate": "2017-12-31",
            "totalAssets": 84524000000,
            "totalLiabilities": null,
            "shareholderEquity": 74347000000,
        },
        {
            "reportDate": "2016-12-31",
            "totalAssets": 64961000000,
            "totalLiabilities": null,
            "shareholderEquity": 59194000000,
        },
        {
            "reportDate": "2015-12-31",
            "totalAssets": 49407000000,
            "totalLiabilities": null,
            "shareholderEquity": 44218000000,
        },
        {
            "reportDate": "2014-12-31",
            "totalAssets": 39966000000,
            "totalLiabilities": null,
            "shareholderEquity": 36096000000,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far; we expect to see a [MCVE] before we can help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to iterate through the items in the collection and perform assignments.

```js
var data = {
  "symbol": "FB",
  "financials": [{
      "reportDate": "2017-12-31",
      "totalAssets": 84524000000,
      "totalLiabilities": null,
      "shareholderEquity": 74347000000,
    },
    {
      "reportDate": "2016-12-31",
      "totalAssets": 64961000000,
      "totalLiabilities": null,
      "shareholderEquity": 59194000000,
    },
    {
      "reportDate": "2015-12-31",
      "totalAssets": 49407000000,
      "totalLiabilities": null,
      "shareholderEquity": 44218000000,
    },
    {
      "reportDate": "2014-12-31",
      "totalAssets": 39966000000,
      "totalLiabilities": null,
      "shareholderEquity": 36096000000,
    }
  ]
};

data.financials.forEach(item => item.totalLiabilities = item.totalAssets - item.shareholderEquity);

console.log('Updated: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.financials.forEach(account => account.totalLiabilities = account.totalAssets - account.shareholderEquity)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Yeah, for sure.